Blazor unhandled exception in edge, debug mode, https
Every blazor project that i run in debug mode/https/microsoft edge throws an unhandled execption.
If i turn on script debugging everything works fine.
Debug mode/https/chrome -> no problems
Debug mode/http/edge -> no problems
It is very specific to debug mode/https/edge.. This worked fine before...
Error message:
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')
      System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'nCQvqEH8VNvHGZoAQZ1kgst_aMtMzS-mZvGg6WU2nEQ'.
      System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore'))
       ---> System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Error: No element is currently associated with component 1
      System.InvalidOperationException: Error: No element is currently associated with component 1
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'nCQvqEH8VNvHGZoAQZ1kgst_aMtMzS-mZvGg6WU2nEQ'.
      System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error: No element is currently associated with component 1)
       ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error: No element is currently associated with component 1
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Tried different modes and different browser.

See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/55063  -- I had the same issue and it turned out it was caused by an update to LastPass Browser Extension. Disabling the extension fixed the issue
